# Duplicating object and default value of property

Tags: python, objects, properties

When I create some property in object:

```
bpy.types.Object.my_prop = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="MyProp",
    default=-1,
    description="My Property"
)
```

and I set the value of this property e.g.: `bpy.context.active_object.my_prop = 10`, then duplicated object will have copied value of original object.

Is there any way how to force to use default value (-1) of property in duplicated object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each property can have callback functions: `update()`, `set()`, `get()` and `get()`, `set()` callback functions allows force to use default value:

```
import bpy

values = {}

def cb_get(self):
    try:
        value = values[self.name]
    except KeyError:
        value = -1 # default value
    return value

def cb_set(self, value):
    values[self.name] = value
    return None

bpy.types.Object.my_prop = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="MyProp",
    description="My Property",
    get=cb_get,
    set=cb_set
    )

print(bpy.context.active_object.my_prop)
bpy.context.active_object.my_prop = 10
print(bpy.context.active_object.my_prop)
```

Example with more explanation can be found in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/jirihnidek/2e5218dd8bf06787e538

**Edit:** Reloading blend file using previous concept is risky (look at comments). Following solution tries to fix problems with reloading blend file.
    import bpy

```
def cb_get(self):
    if self.name != self.name_:
        self.name_ = self.name
        self.my_prop_ = -1 # default value
    return self.my_prop_

def cb_set(self, value):
    self.my_prop_ = value
    return None

bpy.types.Object.my_prop_ = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="MySecretProp",
    default=-1,
    description="My Secret Property",
    options={'HIDDEN'}
    )

bpy.types.Object.name_ = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="SecretName",
    default="",
    description="Expected name of object storing properties",
    options={'HIDDEN'}
    )

bpy.types.Object.my_prop = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="MyProp",
    description="My Property",
    update=cb_update,
    get=cb_get,
    set=cb_set
    )

print(bpy.context.active_object.my_prop)
bpy.context.active_object.my_prop = 10
print(bpy.context.active_object.my_prop)
```

Comment: This is a bit risky, it will work in simple cases - but could give invalid results if you reload files, especially with many names like **Cube.001**, You _could_ have a `bpy.app.handler.load_post` callback to clear the dictionary on file load, but that still wont account for undo/redo. I don't think there is really a fool-proof way to do this.

Comment: If you are willing to consider the name a UUID, you could store some hidden `__name__` custom property. Then on access, check if they don't match, clear all properties, and write into that name. This could cause problems when renaming though.

Comment: Any custom property can not start with '_' character. When you will try to do this, then `ValueError` will be raised. Previous idea is right, but the custom property will have to be named e.g. `name__` and not `__name__` :-).